# How to filter a list with linq depends on counting a property at the same list and take a random group at least minimum total

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my problem, I tried this query (without counting the numOfIps that I want to be a static number)

```
    ips.Where(ip =>!ips.Any(
                            tempIp => tempIp.VLanID != null 
                                && tempIp.VLanID == ip.VLanID 
                                && (tempIp.PackageId > 0 || tempIp.IsReserved !=0))
                        && ip.PackageId == 0
                        && ip.IsReserved == 0
                        ).ToList();
```

**RESULT FROM THE QUERY ON TO TEST LIST DATA (NOT EXPECTED)**

```
IP 100.100.101 WITH VLANID 100 isReserved = 0  PackageId = 0    
IP 100.100.102 WITH VLANID 100 isReserved = 0 PackageId = 0    
IP 400.400.401 WITH VLANID 400 isReserved = 0  PackageId = 0    
IP 400.400.402 WITH VLANID 400 isReserved = 0 PackageId = 0
```

**EXPECTED RESULT LIST**

```
IP 100.100.101 WITH VLANID 100 isReserved = 0  PackageId = 0    
IP 100.100.102 WITH VLANID 100 isReserved = 0 PackageId = 0
```

**DETAILS**

**LIST TEST DATA**

```
IP 100.100.101 WITH VLANID 100 isReserved = 0  PackageId = 0
IP 100.100.102 WITH VLANID 100 isReserved = 0 PackageId = 0
```

(there is no another ip with VLANID == 100 in ips list)

```
IP 200.200.201 WITH VLANID 200 isReserved = 0 PackageId = 0 
IP 200.200.202 WITH VLANID 200 isReserved = 0 PackageId = 1
```

(there is no another IP with VLANID == 200 in ips list)

```
IP 300.300.301 WITH VLANID NULL isReserved = 0 PackageId = 0 
IP 300.300.302 WITH VLANID NULL isReserved = 0 PackageId = 0
IP 400.400.401 WITH VLANID 400 isReserved = 0  PackageId = 0
IP 400.400.402 WITH VLANID 400 isReserved = 0 PackageId = 0
```

I want to take a random group of ips (that belongs to the same vlanId) from ips list that:

- there is not an ip with the same vlanid that has PackageId > 0 || IsReserved !=0
- this group has at least numOfIps
- I want to take the first group that matches these rules and not all groups with different vlanids
  (somehow distinct or firstordefault… I don’t know)

I want to help me fix this query or create a new one with linq.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how you wanted the null vlanids handled... Did you never want to return those?  If so, just add a .Where(v=>v.vlandid!=null) at the end of the other Where clauses.  The code supplied is able to be dropped into [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) (using statements).  Feel free to play with it as needed.

```
var ips= new[]{
  new {ip="100.100.101",VLanID=(int?)100,isReserved=0,PackageId=0},
  new {ip="100.100.102",VLanID=(int?)100,isReserved=0,PackageId=0},
  new {ip="200.200.201",VLanID=(int?)200,isReserved=0,PackageId=0},
  new {ip="200.200.202",VLanID=(int?)200,isReserved=0,PackageId=1},
  new {ip="300.300.301",VLanID=(int?)null,isReserved=0,PackageId=0},
  new {ip="300.300.302",VLanID=(int?)null,isReserved=0,PackageId=0},
  new {ip="400.400.401",VLanID=(int?)400,isReserved=0,PackageId=0},
  new {ip="400.400.402",VLanID=(int?)400,isReserved=0,PackageId=0}
};
var numOfIps=2;
var result=ips.GroupBy(k=>k.VLanID)
 .Where(v=>v.Count()>=numOfIps)
 .Where(v=>v.All(i=>i.isReserved==0))
 /*.Where(v=>v.Key!=null)  Remove null vlans */
 /*.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()) Pseudo Randomize */
 .First(v=>v.All(i=>i.PackageId==0))
 .Select(v=>v);

result.Dump();
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Updated answer with removing null vlans, and doing a pseudo random.  Remove either of those lines if that isn't what you wanted.  It will now choose at random the 100 VLAN and 400 VLAN since both meet your criteria.

Comment: Updated a little . Based on your idea the final one is:           var numOfIps = 2;
            var result = ips.GroupBy(k => k.VLanID)
                .Where(v => v.Count() >= numOfIps)
                .Where(v => v.All(i => i.IsReserved == 0)).First(v => !v.Any(i => i.PackageId > 0))
             .Select(v => v).ToList();
            return result;

Comment: Updated answer to more closely reflect your changes.  I also flipped the First() call to use All just like you flipped the other Where clause just to be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

You can group your results by `VLanID` and return first of them:

```
ips.Where(ip => !ips.Any(
        tempIp => tempIp.VLanID != null
            && tempIp.VLanID == ip.VLanID
            && (tempIp.PackageId > 0 || tempIp.IsReserved != 0))
    && ip.PackageId == 0
    && ip.IsReserved == 0
    ).GroupBy(i => i.VLanID).First().ToList();
```

If result can be empty you should use `FirstOrDefault` then threat null cases. I also don't know how you are using the result, since `IGrouping` is an `IEnumerable` the `.ToList()` conversion may not be necessary.

Comment: It was quick fix .Let me check this .Thanks

Comment: Not working .when I removed .100 ips set it took the .400 set which had null vlanid and it is wrong.